# soundmanager2 IE playback issue

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm currently working with soundmanager2 in an IE/flash context (not html5). The issue is that audio playback of mp3 content does not occur for the following case where the 'onload' callback function is defined as null OR as a function that does almost nothing.

```
soundManager.createSound({
               id: 'someidforasoundfile',
               url: 'pathtoaudiofile.mp3',
               autoLoad: true,
               autoPlay: true,
               onload: function() {
                               return 1;
               },
               volume: 50
});
```

If I define the "onload" callback as:

```
function() { alert('zing'); }
```

soundmanager2 will actually start playing the audio file...but there's an annoying alert pop up that the user has to contend with.

Is this a soundmanager2 configuration issue or something else?

Thanks in advance!

ct

Answer (score 0):

I think im understanding is that when a user indicates a stream, theres a message alert to indicate that the song is starting or they have to let permission.

I would say its soundmanager, As flash can stream or download media content with out any "USER" permissions.
this is limited/ restricted of course to:Examples mp3,video,other SWF files.ect

but say downloading zipfiles or other media types may need permissions.

They maybe something in the (alert) function, to create this message or pop up to appear, check that source code and follow its script.

if you have some source code for this please post i will take a look at it

Comment: thanks for the post - the code looks exactly as i've represented it here - the url's and files names have been removed b/c it's not really pertinent to the issue.

Comment: soundManager is a library or class file im guessing, so look in the folder and check their scripts.